# Exclude from portfolio all markets that make a loss in backtests

Tags: algorithmic-trading, hedge-fund

I'm backtesting a pattern recognition strategy over 20 years across 40 futures markets. In my live trading portfolio, should I exclude all markets that made a loss over the 20 year backtest period?

Comment: Do you know that they will make a loss in the future?

Comment: It very strongly depends on a number of factors, including the strategy and how much you think historical data is a good estimate of what could happen in the future.  (Even assuming long-only.)

If the historical data says that the index drops 1% for two days and then rises 1%, then it will make a loss over any long period, but you have a pattern where you can make money by buying and selling.

Comment: Many CTA's (Commodity trading hedge funds) trade a single strategy in multiple futures markets because they cannot predict which market will be profitable in what year and they hope that by trading 40 markets they will have a more consistent profit over time. How they choose those markets is a whole other discussion; as Rylan said, it depends on the type of strategy you are employing and where you think it *may* be successful.